# How to sample accelerometer data in the background or on the sleep mode

Tags: java, android

I have a program which will sample accelerometer data all the time and do some analysis. But I find that when pressing the power button or in the sleep mode, the system will not sample data after a period of time. Does anybody know how to let accelerometer run in the background to collect data?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Are you doing your processing in the activity or in a service?  Answer 1 is correct, because I believe the accelerometers are powered down during sleep, but, an activity will be subject to gc, as well.  I would suggest using a service instead if you aren't already.  "program" was ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK which will keep the CPU running and still allow the screen to go off.  Of course, the battery will run down faster.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Comment: You may also need to put your code into a foreground service. I had to do that when trying to record audio with the screen off: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57260468/2441655