# How to collect accelerometer data while the phone is in the idle state

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I’m currently working on an application which is supposed to collect accelerometer and microphone data every two seconds. To do so, I started a service (running a timer inside) in order to collect the data while the application is running in the background. So far so good.

The timer initiates, collects the data and writes that data on a XML file. But after taking a look at the produced XML file I realized that, while the phone is in the idle state, the accelerometer value is the always the same. I even use a wake lock in order to “wake” the phone every two seconds but even that did not work.

Here’s the relevant code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Background Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Service");

    this.startActivities();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Kill timer, sensors and XML file
    this.stopActivities();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Background Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Background Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

/**
 * Expanded modification function. 
 */
private void startExpandedNotification(){
    //Id for the intent of the expanded notification
    final int myID = 1234;

    //The intent to launch when the user clicks the expanded notification
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainMovement.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    //This constructor is deprecated. Use Notification.Builder instead if programming for 3.0+
    Notification notice = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Movement Sampling Activated", System.currentTimeMillis());

    //This method is deprecated. Use Notification.Builder instead if programming for 3.0+
    notice.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Movement Sampling", "Sensors activated", pendIntent);

    notice.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(myID, notice);
}

/**
 * Stop Expanded Notification
 */
private void stopExpandedNotification(){
    stopForeground(true);
}

/**
 * Starts everything that the service needs to collect the sensors data 
 * (timer, xml file, sensors, expanded notification)
 */
private void startActivities() {
    // Define output file path
    OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Ze";// also added ""/Ze here
    OUTPUT_FILE += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

    timer = new Timer(); // If I take this line out, it will lead to an
                            // exception. But if I do so, the acc values are
                            // measured while the phone is in the idle state (works only on samsung spika)
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, _refreshRate);

    xml = new DataStore();

    this.startRecordingMic();
    this.startRecordingAcc();

    startExpandedNotification();

    _sampling = true;
}

/**
 * Stops everything that the service needs to collect the sensors data 
 * (timer, xml file, sensors, expanded notification)
 */
private void stopActivities() {
    timer.cancel();
    //Log.e(TAG, "timer: CANCELLED");

    // close xml file
    xml.closeFile();
    //Log.e(TAG, "XML: CLOSED");

    // unregister sensor
    _sensorManager.unregisterListener(accelerationListener);
    //Log.e(TAG, "Sensors: UNREGISTERED");

    // stop recording
    if (_recorder != null) {
        _recorder.stop();
        _recorder.release();
        _recorder = null;
    }

    stopExpandedNotification();

    _sampling = false;
}

/**
 * Responsible for collecting the sensors data every two seconds
 */
private class mainTask extends TimerTask {
    /**
     * Collects the sensor data every 2 seconds
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MovementService.this.collectData();
    }
}

/**
 * Initiates the microphone in order to collect the amplitude value
 */
private void startRecordingMic() {
    _recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    _recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    _recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    _recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    _recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);

    try {
        _recorder.prepare();
    } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    _recorder.start();
}

/**
 * Initiates the acceleromenter sensor in order to collect movement data
 */
private void startRecordingAcc() {
    // ACCELEROMETER
    _sensorManager = (SensorManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    _accelerometer = _sensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    _sensorManager.registerListener(accelerationListener, _accelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

private final SensorEventListener accelerationListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int acc) {
    }


    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // sampling values per axis
        _x = event.values[0];
        _y = event.values[1];
        _z = event.values[2];

        //Log.e(TAG , "x: " + _x + "  y: " + _y + " z:" + _z);
    }
};

/**
 * Send data (amplitude and decibel) to the xml file
 */
public void collectData() {
    //The power lock ensures that the service will indeed collect the accelerometer data
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) MovementService.this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "YOUR TAG");
    wl.acquire();
    Log.v(TAG, "lock aquired");

    if (xml != null) xml.writeOnFile(this.getAmplitude(), this.getAccelaration(), this.getTotalAccelaration());

    wl.release();
    Log.v(TAG, "lock released");
}
```

Have you guys any suggestion in order to solve this problem? This is driving me crazy.

Ps: I’m using a Samsung spika, android version 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the accelerometer cannot be sampled when the device is idle. You'll need to set a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK which will keep the CPU running. It still allows the screen to go off but of course, the battery will run down faster than normal.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

code:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
//  ..screen will stay on during this section..
wl.release();
```

You also have to include this permission entry in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

There is a previous question on this point:
[How to sample accelerometer data in the background or on the sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766274/how-to-sample-accelerometer-data-in-the-background-or-on-the-sleep-mode)

Comment: You may also need to put your code into a foreground service. I had to do that when trying to record audio when the screen is off: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57260468/2441655